# No provider for TemplateRef! (NgIf ->TemplateRef)

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to show a checkmark if an answer is the accepted answer:

```
template: `<div ngIf="answer.accepted">&#10004;</div>`
```

But I get this error:

```
EXCEPTION: No provider for TemplateRef! (NgIf ->TemplateRef)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 879, accepted):

You missed the `*` in front of NgIf (like we all have, dozens of times):

```
<div *ngIf="answer.accepted">&#10004;</div>
```

---

Without the `*`, Angular sees that the `ngIf` directive is being applied to the `div` element, but since there is no `*` or `<template>` tag, it is unable to locate a template, hence the error.

---

If you get this error with Angular v5:

> Error: StaticInjectorError[TemplateRef]:
>  
>       StaticInjectorError[TemplateRef]: 
>         NullInjectorError: No provider for TemplateRef!

You may have `<template>...</template>` in one or more of your component templates.  Change/update the tag to `<ng-template>...</ng-template>`.

Comment: The same excpetion can also occur if you use ngSwitchCase without the asterisk!

Comment: i wanted to upvote this, but i see that i already did a long time ago.

Comment: Couldn't the error-checker notice it starts with ng and add at the bottom: "ng__ found, did you mean *ng__ ?"  (Maybe they think that's holding the dev's hand too helpfully.)

Answer (score 13):

So, I can help to understand what (and where) you made the mistake, but before it, we need to read the documentation:

> Access a TemplateRef instance by placing a directive on an
>  element (or directive prefixed with *). The TemplateRef
> for the embedded view is injected into the constructor of the
> directive, using the TemplateRef token.
>
> You can also use a Query to find a TemplateRef associated with a
> component or a directive.

So:

- When using `[ngIf]="something"` you must use `<ng-template>` to access the template ref (eg: when using `<template>` or `<ng-template>`);
- Using `*ngIf` you can use it where you want 'cause the * garante the access to template ref(eg: when using `<span>` or `<div>`);

If you're using in your code something like `<span [ngIf]="message"> {{message}}</span>` you probably gonna get some error.

Comment: fantastic. You solved my problem. somehow  <template> must be replaced with <ng-<template> to function

Comment: You're welcome sir. <3

Answer (score 5):

it's a common misconception to miss a few syntaxes in writing the code , one such popular mistake everyone tries to make is not using * before ngIf , which when used makes angular compiler to read ngIf as template reference variable and checks for local reference for the variable which wont be found in the file. so please check for these mistakes and learn form them if possible

```
<div *ngIf="answer.accepted">&#10004;</div>
```

Comment: Hmm. Thank you for contributing. But how is this answer different from @Mark_Rajcok's?