# Angular2 - Directive not working when not declared in the same module

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-modules, viewchild

I have a directive and I want to use it in multiple modules. Declaring it on each modules produces an error. Thus, I tried to declare it in a shared module and import this shared module to other modules. However, it didn't work. It only works when it is declared exactly on the component's own module.

Here is my `SharedModule`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { GeneralDataService } from './general-data.service';
import {ModalDirective} from '../directives/modal.directive';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule
      ],
      providers: [GeneralDataService],
      declarations: [ModalDirective]
    })
    export class SharedModule { }
```

And the module that I want to use `ModalDirective`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MyComponent } from './patient.component';
import {SharedModule} from '../shared/shared.module';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [  ],
  declarations: [ MyComponent ]
})
export class MyModule { }
```

In `MyComponent` component:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(ModalDirective) modal: ModalDirective;

  ...
}
```

`modal` in `MyComponent` is `undefined` (even in `ngAfterViewInit`) if `ModalDirective` is not declared in `MyModule`. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your `SharedModule` you need to `export` the `ModalDirective`

```
...

@NgModule{(
   ...
   exports: [ModalDirective]
)}
export class SharedModule { ... }
```

See [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module) on shared modules for more info

Comment: Thx Fredrik! My directive has an injection of `TemplateRef`. However when I add the directive into the `NgModule.exports` list, I got an error says `No provider for TemplateRef!`. Any ideas?

Comment: @cosmozhang - can't really tell without seeing your code, but have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932074/angular2-no-provider-for-templateref-ngif-templateref

Comment: For me it doesn't work even after adding it to exports